# Missing constant in BubbleWrap in rubymotion 3.8

Tags: rubymotion

I got `#<NameError: uninitialized constant BubbleWrap::HTTP>`,

And I have no idea what's wrong with it

There is no **HTTP** method in **BW** object.

```
    BW.constants.grep(/htt/mi)
    => [:MCHTTPRequestor, :NSHTTPURLResponseInternal, :NSHTTPURLResponse, :MCGlobalHTTPProxyPayload, :NSHTTPURLRequestParameters, :NSHTTPCookieStorage, :MCHTTPTransaction, :NSHTTPCookieStorageInternal, :NSHTTPCookie, :CILightTunnel]

(main)> BW::HTTP
2015-04-14 13:27:51.673 hello[80662:629086] uninitialized constant BubbleWrap::HTTP (NameError)
=> #<NameError: uninitialized constant BubbleWrap::HTTP>

% motion --version
3.8

-  bubble-wrap (1.8.0)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the BW::HTTP module, or is this popping up without you trying to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP library has been deprecated, but you can find it at github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap-HTTP (`gem "bubble-wrap-http"`)

Comment: it is deprecated in favor of what?